# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory continue for the rest of file when some files are not accessible in the dir

Tags: c#

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(source_dir, target_dir) will throw exception and stop the zipping when any file in the directory is being accessed. how can I make it do the zipping for the rest of the files ??

Killing the processes are not allowed, they are vital.

Thanks

Resolved:

Here is how I get this around.
Split the task into 2 phase.

(Note only use the Zipfile and ZipArchive from System.IO.Compression)

Step 1. create a dummy zip file; (this must not hit access issue)

Step 2. Scan and Add files to the dummy zip file

Additional: Keep the original directory hierarchy by adding folder into the dummy zip file

Here is the Step 2, only copy the file when hit exception.

```
        private void UpdateBallFile(String source_dir, String target_zipfile)
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(target_zipfile + suffix, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (String subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(source_dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                String relatedPath = subdir.Replace(source_dir, String.Empty);
                String entry = relatedPath.Replace("\\", "/").Substring(1);
                foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(file))
                    {
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                        try
                        {
                            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, entry+"/"+info.Name);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                String copied_item = Path.Combine(@"c:\", info.Name);
                                File.Copy(file, copied_item, true);
                                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(copied_item, entry + "/" + info.Name);
                                File.Delete(copied_item);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                UpdateLog(String.Format("Fails to zip: {0}, {1} ", file, ex.Message));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

I am new to C# and this community, Please let me know if you have better idea.

Thanks

Comment: Can you lock the files so they can't be accessed in the moment of zipping?

Comment: No. the background process may panic. But skipping of those files are acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can add each file to your zip by checking the accessibility, so you can code like this:

```
ZipFile myzip = new ZipFile("myzipFile");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\sample"))
{
    try
    {
        var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        stream.Dispose();
        myzip.AddFile(file);// add file to zip only if it is accessible. else it will throw some exception 
        //hence it wont added to the zipped folder.
    }
    catch 
    { }              
}
myzip.Save(@"D:\sample\myfile.zip");// this zip file contains only file that have access
```

Hope that this is actually you ware looking;

Comment: You should use `FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read` -- if another process has the file open for read, and has allowed read sharing, that's fine. However, the code has a race condition; what if something else opens the file immediately between the `stream.Dispose()` and the `myzip.AddFile()`?

Comment: "what if something else opens the file immediately between the stream.Dispose() and the myzip.AddFile()? " Yes, will this corrupt the zipfile? I will test this sample and see if it can work correctly in race condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be preparing a kind of copy/temp folder in the **User/AppData/Local** directory, where all readable files are in. You will than zip this folder, because you can be sure that the data are not used. After the zip-process you have to delete the folder. Not the optimum but it should work. Another solution would be using some other zip component...

Comment: yes, this will be the last resort i may come up to , but the files can be few hundred gigabytes :-(, thanks!

Comment: You can never be sure that the files aren't in use by something. Many systems perform back ground maintenance tasks from time to time, such as defragging or anti-virus scanning.